# css: header gets stuck when rotating device

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

On my wordpress blog ([www.taxbox.at](http://www.taxbox.at)) I added some code to make the header sticky and shrink. It works fine on every device except when you rotate the device (mobile phone or tablet) into landscape mode. After rotating the header is displayed incorrectly.  It seems that the header does not automatically change format when the device changes into landscape mode and the page has to be reloaded manually to fix it. [picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTW5v.jpg)

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?
I am grateful for every input!

```html
.shrinker {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear!important;
}

.shrinker.elementor-sticky--effects {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
    padding-top: 3px!important;
    padding-bottom: 3px!important;
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 30px -4px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear!important;
}

/* shrinking logo image */

.shrinking-logo img {
    width: 150px!important;
    transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear!important;
}

.shrinker.elementor-sticky--effects img {
    width: 130px!important;
    transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear!important;
}

/* shrinking menu */

.shrinker.elementor-sticky--effects ul li a {
    font-size: 1.3rem!important;
    transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear!important;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear!important;
}


/* Tablet and Mobile Menu Shrinking */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    /* shrinking background */
    
.shrinker.elementor-sticky--effects {
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 5px!important;
    padding-bottom: 7px!important;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px -4px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
    
    /* shrinking image */

.shrinker.elementor-sticky--effects img {
    width: 135px!important;
}
    
    /* shrinking menu */

.shrinker.elementor-sticky--effects ul li a {
    font-size: 1.2rem!important;
}



/* End Of Shrinking Sticky Menu */
```

Comment: You have to apply mobile rotating device CSS for that

Comment: Thanks, now I know that I have to google for!